# Resetting an animation when it is triggered again in React (using hooks) - Sliding Text

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm building a simple music app that connects to Spotify. 
If the name of the song/artist is too **long** (text is overflowing) an **animation** makes an adjacent copy of the text and then it *slides* the two of them left - infinitely.

The problem is that if the long text has been replaced with another long text the animation doesn't reset, but just continues from the middle.
**I try to remove the class and then immediately add it but this method doesn't work.**

The class is called '*active_animation*' and it is conditionally rendered with React.

The variables `isOverflowingTitle` and `isOverflowingNames`, when set to true, activate the animation. Whenever a new song updates the `useEffect` is triggered.

[image]

This is my code:

```
import React, { useContext, useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ArtistsLinksBySong from '../ArtistsLinksBySong';
import { PlayerSourceContext } from '../../store/PlayerSourceContext';

export default () => {
  const [playerSource] = useContext(PlayerSourceContext);
  const containerTagRef = useRef(null);
  const songTitleTag = useRef(null);
  const artistNamesTag = useRef(null);
  const [isOverflowingTitle, setIsOverflowingTitle] = useState(false);
  const [isOverflowingNames, setIsOverflowingNames] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let mainPixelWidth = containerTagRef.current.clientWidth;
    artistNamesTag.current.clientWidth > mainPixelWidth - 16
      ? setIsOverflowingNames(true)
      : setIsOverflowingNames(false);

    songTitleTag.current.clientWidth > mainPixelWidth - 16
      ? setIsOverflowingTitle(true)
      : setIsOverflowingTitle(false);
  }, [playerSource]);

  const getSongArtists = () => {
    if (playerSource.artists) {
      return <ArtistsLinksBySong artistArrOfObj={playerSource.artists} />;
    } else {
      return 'Artist Name';
    }
  };
  const getSongTitle = () => {
    if (playerSource.name) {
      return String(playerSource.name);
    } else {
      return 'Track Title';
    }
  };

  return (
    <div id='player-song-text-container' ref={containerTagRef}>
      <div id='title-name-text'>
        <div id='move-control'>
          <div
            id='move1'
            ref={songTitleTag}
            className={isOverflowingTitle ? 'active_animation' : ''}
          >
            {getSongTitle()}
          </div>
          {isOverflowingTitle && (
            <div className='adjacent-copy'>{getSongTitle()}</div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id='artists-names-text'>
        <div id='move-control2'>
          <div
            id='move2'
            ref={artistNamesTag}
            className={isOverflowingNames ? 'active_animation' : ''}
          >
            {getSongArtists()}
          </div>
          {isOverflowingNames && (
            <div className='adjacent-copy'>{getSongArtists()}</div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id='left-shade'></div>
      <div id='right-shade'></div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

How would you guys solve this issue?

And btw, this is the repo: https://github.com/itayperry/react_spotify_player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like bad practice - but this `setTimeout(() => {....}, 0)` solves the issue:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let mainPixelWidth = containerTagRef.current.clientWidth;
    setTimeout(() => {
      artistNamesTag.current.clientWidth > mainPixelWidth - 16
        ? setIsOverflowingNames(true)
        : setIsOverflowingNames(false);

      songTitleTag.current.clientWidth > mainPixelWidth - 16
        ? setIsOverflowingTitle(true)
        : setIsOverflowingTitle(false);
    }, 0);

    return () => {
      setIsOverflowingNames(false); // reset this animation
      setIsOverflowingTitle(false); // reset this animation
    };
  }, [playerSource]);
```